# GeoServer REST API - create layer group and generate bounding box

Tags: layers, extents, geoserver-rest-api

I would like to create a layer group and generate bounds.

My REST URL: .../geoserver/rest/layergroups

Parameter:

```xml
<layerGroup>
   <name>map</name>
   <mode>NAMED</mode>
   <title>map</title>
   <workspace>
      <name>maps</name>
   </workspace>
   <layers>
      <layer>
         <name>maps:layer1</name>
      </layer>
      <layer>
         <name>maps:layer2</name>
      </layer>
   </layers>
   <bounds>
      <crs class="projected">EPSG:3857</crs>
   </bounds>
</layerGroup>
```

Layer group is created correctly, but how to generate bounds ?

Answer (score 0):

As with all REST questions the solution is to make a GET request of an existing resource to see how it is done, so `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layergroups/tiger-ny.xml` gives:

```
<layerGroup>
  <name>tiger-ny</name>
  <mode>SINGLE</mode>
  <title>TIGER New York</title>
  <abstractTxt>Topologically Integrated Geographic Encoding and Referencing (TIGER) dataset for New York.</abstractTxt>
  <publishables>
    <published type="layer">
      <name>tiger:giant_polygon</name>
      <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/tiger/layers/giant_polygon.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </published>
    <published type="layer">
      <name>tiger:poly_landmarks</name>
      <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/tiger/layers/poly_landmarks.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </published>
    <published type="layer">
      <name>tiger:tiger_roads</name>
      <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/tiger/layers/tiger_roads.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </published>
    <published type="layer">
      <name>tiger:poi</name>
      <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/tiger/layers/poi.xml" type="application/xml"/>
    </published>
  </publishables>
  <styles>
    <style/>
    <style/>
    <style/>
    <style/>
  </styles>
  <bounds>
    <minx>-74.047185</minx>
    <maxx>-73.907005</maxx>
    <miny>40.679648</miny>
    <maxy>40.882078</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </bounds>
  <metadata>
    <entry key="rawStyleList"></entry>
  </metadata>
</layerGroup>
```

so the answer is just add the coordinates:

```
 <bounds>
    <minx>-74.047185</minx>
    <maxx>-73.907005</maxx>
    <miny>40.679648</miny>
    <maxy>40.882078</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </bounds>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I would like to generate boundaries, not pass them in a parameter.
This would be the equivalent of a "Generate Bounds" button in the geoserver admin panel or equivalent "recalculate" parameter for featuretypes REST requests.

Comment: is that not what you get if you don't specify it